# Retrofit return boolean value

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to run changesHasBeenSaved if saveChanges function gives me true value.
How can I get boolean or string or integer, any value, when Retrofit finish?
Is it possible?

I need a function similar this:

```
public boolean saveChanges()
{
    Boolean output = false;
    RequestAPI requestAPI = Requests.getRetrofit();
    Call<Object> jsonObjectCall = requestAPI.readAllCategoeies();

    jsonObjectCall.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
            if(response.body() != null) {
                output = true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });

    return output;
}
```

Comment: what about writing a method and calling it inside the if statement?

Comment: Can you show me example??

Comment: **How can I get boolean or string or integer, any value, when Retrofit finish?** from where you want to get it ? did you mean want to parse the api response ?

Comment: I need a boolean, if Retrofit done return true, if not return false... I want call it in function saveChanges()

Comment: I mean why don't you just call changesHasBeenSaved inside if statement?

Comment: saveChanges function is on Updates.class
changesHasBeenSaved  function is on Profile.class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change method return type `boolean` to `void` as retrofit work asynchronous.

You should pass the listener/callback to get the status in callback.

First create callback interface like below

```
public interface ApiCallback {
   void onResponse(boolean success);
}
```

Here how saveChanges will look like

```
public void saveChanges(final ApiCallback callback)
{
    RequestAPI requestAPI = Requests.getRetrofit();
    Call<Object> jsonObjectCall = requestAPI.readAllCategoeies();
    jsonObjectCall.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
            callback.onResponse(response.body() != null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
            callback.onResponse(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you need to call saveChanges method like below

```
saveChanges(new ApiCallback () {
   public void onResponse(boolean success){
        if(success){
          // do something
        } else{
          // do something
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Glad to know, Awesome !!

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonObjectCall.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
       //when the response is successful

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            output = true;

            // display response as string 
            Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());

            //Object user1 = response.body(); maps response to the modal class


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
        call.cancel();
    }
})
```

Change you call back to like the above , included comments for clearity about usage .

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what I wanted

Comment: output is true  when the reponse is successful and in the else case and inside OnFaliure ,set output false,  you could return it from your return statement inside the fuction. Is it not that you want?

Comment: There is an error: Variable 'output' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.

Comment: just make it final, it happens when accessing a local variable of outer class inside a nested class.

Comment: It seems making it final  was the problem that did not allow it to change ,should have worked with a global (output) variable. Glad to know you got the solution.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Dont be, it is ok :)